# A function which increments a string, to create a new string

Tags: java, parsing, integer

write a function which increments a string, to create a new string.

- If the string already ends with a number, the number should be incremented by 1.
- If the string does not end with a number. the number 1 should be appended to the new string.

Examples:

```
foo - foo1 
foobar23 - foobar24 
foo0042 - foo0043 
foo9 - foo10 
foo099 - foo100
```

Attention: If the number has leading zeros the amount of digits should be considered.

The program passed tests on the CodeWars platform, except for one
For input string: "1712031362069931272877416673"
she falls on it

```
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
```

but in IJ it works correctly ...
Any idea why?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(incrementString("foo001"));
        System.out.println(incrementString("33275375531813209960"));
        System.out.println(incrementString("0000004617702678077138438340108"));
    }

    public static String incrementString(String str) {
        boolean isNumeric = str.chars().allMatch( Character::isDigit );
        if(str.isEmpty())
            return "1";

        else if (isNumeric) {
            BigInteger b = new BigInteger(str);
            return String.format("%0"+str.length() + "d",b.add(BigInteger.valueOf(1)));
        }
        String timeRegex = "(.*)(\\D)([0-9]*)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(timeRegex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String sec = matcher.group(3);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (sec.isEmpty()) {
                sec = "0";
                return str + sb+(Integer.parseInt(sec) + 1);
            } else {
                int length = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(sec) + 1).length();
                if (sec.length() > length) {

                    for (int i = length; i < sec.length(); i++) {
                        sb.append("0");
                    }
                }
                return str.substring(0,str.length() - sec.length()) + String.format("%0"+sec.length() + "d",Integer.parseInt(sec)+1);
            }
        }
      else
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: a String is not a numerical format, so you can't "increment" a String. What you can do, is parse a String to a numerical format (which is what you're doing, and where it fails), augment it, and parse it back to a String. "foo3" or similar, are not numerical values, and can't be parsed to a numerical type. put a breakpoint on the line where the error occurs, or add a print statement to see the String values you're trying to parse

Comment: `if(str == "")` is wrong already as I'd doubt `str` would ever be the same instance as the empty string literal. You need `if(str.equals(""))` or `if(str.isEmpty())` instead.

Comment: @Stultuske that is already what the OP does

Comment: Can you share the full staktrace ? [edit] and add it

Comment: The number is to big for an integer

Comment: You're using `BigInteger` for numeric strings already, which is correct as those could be large. But is there anything that let's you assume the numbers in a alpha-numeric string all fit into the `int` range? Why don't you use `BigInteger` there as well?

Comment: input data can be like

`fooboo2212031362069931272877416699`
and out 
`fooboo2212031362069931272877416700`

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. Try using `Integer.parseInt("2212031362069931272877416699")` and see the result - that's what you're doing in the bottom portion of your code. (Hint: those numbers don't fit into the `Integer` range).

Comment: all `Integer.parseInt(***)` needs to be replaced with
 `BigInteger a = new BigInteger(***)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `Integer.parseInt(sec)` when trying to parse a value too long to fix in a int (max is 2 billion)

You need to use `BigInteger` everywhere, also there is much useless code. You can also capture the zeros in the first group of the regex, so you don't have leading zeros to take care

```
public static String incrementString(String str) {
    boolean isNumeric = str.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit);
    if (str.isEmpty()) {
        return "1";
    } else if (isNumeric) {
        BigInteger b = new BigInteger(str);
        return String.format("%0" + str.length() + "d", b.add(BigInteger.ONE));
    }

    String timeRegex = "(.*\\D0*)([1-9][0-9]*)";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(timeRegex).matcher(str);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        String sec = matcher.group(2);
        if (sec.isEmpty()) {
            return str + 1;
        } else {
            BigInteger new_value = new BigInteger(sec).add(BigInteger.ONE);
            return matcher.group(1) + new_value;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How would you solve this problem by hand? I'll bet you wouldn't require a calculator.

The way I would do would be to just look at the last character in the string:

1. If the string is empty or the last character is not a digit, append the character `1`.
2. If the last character is one of the digits `0` to `8`, change it to the next digit.
3. If the last character is the digit `9`:

   - Remove all the trailing `9`s
   - Apply whichever of (1) or (2) above is appropriate.
   - Append the same number of `0`s as the number of `9`s you removed.

You can implement that simple algorithm in a few lines, without BigInteger and without regexes.

This seems to work, although I didn't test it thoroughly with different Unicode scripts (and I'm really not a Java programmer):

```java
    public static String incrementString(String str) {
        if (str.isEmpty())
            return "1";
        char lastChar = str.charAt(str.length()-1);
        if (!Character.isDigit(lastChar)) 
            return str + "1";
        String prefix = str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
        if (Character.digit(lastChar, 10) != 9)
            return prefix + (char)(lastChar + 1);
        return incrementString(prefix) + (char)(lastChar - 9);
    }
```